# Word for officially and legally confirm a decision

Tags: single-word-requests

If a decision or proposal is presented there might be some instance that needs to take the final and official or legal decision. This last "decision" is mostly a confirmation to make it have effect.

Is there a word for this latter "decision"?

"Confirm" is too weak since that sounds like the decision was already taken in full. "Decide" does not feel right since the latter decision is "upping" the decision to official status.

Comment: What other synonyms for *confirm* did you consider?

Comment: Happens a lot with EU institutions. They tend to talk about the final step being adoption of the decision by the relevant (or as they would say, competent) body. Ratification is for situations where there was some procedural defect in the original decision, e.g. a board of directors makes a decision that goes beyond its powers under the company's constitution, but the shareholders ratify it, and it is then treated as if it had been validly made in the the first place. It's also used for international treaties where there are typically several parties...

Comment: ... so for what it's worth I'm not sure that's a great fit. Ruling is for judicial or quasi-legal decisions only, and even within that area it is pretty much confined to decisions on points of law or procedure (as distinct from factual decisions). It does not imply that some earlier proposal or decision is being confirmed, so doesn't seem to be a fit.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of "final and official or legal decision" you had in mind: whether either of the Answers satisfactorily answers you Q. or whether you meant something else?

Comment: "certify" would be a word to confirm something more like completeness

Comment: I think "certify" would be a good fit here. I was thinking about the situation where a working group in a company presents its decision on a wording or procedure and some other more "official" instance, like a steering committe or board, gives it its weight, rather than substance. "Sanction" might work too, but sounds as it would indicate some more "legal" context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for "sanctioned". But considered "certified" as a strong runner up. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try *ratification*.

Ratification is defined in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ratification) as:

> the action of signing or giving formal consent to a treaty, contract, or agreement, making it officially valid

E.g.:

> "ratification of the treaty raised problems in several member states"

Comment: In my understanding, **ratification** refers to situations where the wording of a document, agreement, or (often) treaty has *already* been finalised / agreed, and then individual parties (often countries, states, etc.) agree to be bound by the terms of that treaty or other agreement. This could be well *beyond* the original finalisation of the wording of the "agreement", and could even be many years after the treaty/agreement initially came into force by other parties have 'ratified' it earlier. It is not clear whether this is what the Q. has in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's ***RULING***.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruling) :

*ruling*

: an official or authoritative decision, decree, statement, or interpretation 
(as by a judge on a point of law).

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

"The author further notes that the Court of Appeal mentions in its ***ruling*** that its ***rulings*** are final, and does not indicate any other remedy available to the parties."

Comment: ***Ruling*** is appropriate when one party (e.g. a judge) is adjudicating between two opposing parties; see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ruling) and [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ruling).  But that term does not seem to me to be appropriate in the context in which I understand the Q., namely that a 'provisional' "decision or proposal" has been made and needs to be 'confirmed' or 'finalised'.

Answer (score 0):

In matters involving legal contracts, the term [**executed**](https://legaldictionary.net/executed-contract/) is typically used, at least in the U.S.

A contract may be agreed to between the negotiators, but it must be signed by the principals before it has full legal effect.